# Grails - Security Encoding By Default

Tags: security, grails, groovy, xss, sql-injection

I submitted data up to a controller in Grails and did a javascript injection which worked. I was surprised as I figured the default would be to encode parameters as they came into the controllers. Can I set this easily so that all parameters are encoded when they hit the controller? Also, am I safe to do a GORM `create` with the text as it came up, or is this vulnerable to SQL injection? I see [in the guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html) how to prevent SQL Injection for a `find` query, but what about object creation?

I also saw that there is an `encodeAsHTML` method that I can call to encode on the way back down to the client. Wouldn't I want to do this before it went into the database so that I only have to encode once? Thanks!

Comment: there's also `encodeAsJavaScript()`

Answer (score 10):

#### User Input

The idea of "sanitizing your inputs" (or pre-encoding or pre-escaping) your content is a terrible one.  It does not actually protect you when you really need it, and leads to all sorts of design headaches.  Even PHP finally dumped the technique.

It's always better to handle the data via proper APIs correctly, which eliminates the risk.  For example, SQL injections is *absolutely* eliminated using prepared statements or statements with placeholders for the content.  This technique has been around for a very long time (as long as I've using Java & SQL).

Grails (GORM) automatically handles encoding any content that is saved via the objects, including setting a single property, creating a new object and saving it, or setting properties via `obj.properties = params` or something similar.

As long as you are using GORM, there is no risk of SQL injection.

#### Content Storage

Also, it's generally considered incorrect to store the already-encoded information in the database, as that encoding would only be correct for a given display type (such as HTML).  If you instead wanted to render it using JSON, the HTML encoding is incorrect.  XML is also slightly different, and there are times when you might prefer plain text, too.

Instead, you generally should store the raw (UTF8 or similar) data in the database, and convert it to the correct display type when it is being rendered for display.  Note that it's converted *when it's being rendered* — this doesn't necessarily mean every time you send it to the client.  You can use a variety of caching techniques to make sure this doesn't happen too often — including the [new cache plugin added to Grails 2.1](http://grails.org/plugin/cache).

#### Preventing [XSS Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

One highly recommended technique, however, is to set the default view codec to HTML, using the [`grails.views.default.codec` option](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#builtInOptions), like this:

```
grails.views.default.codec = 'html'
```

This will only affect GSPs, and only content echoed using dollar-sign syntax (`${foo}`).  This gives you the flexibility of overriding this behavior using tags (the recommended way) or the `<%= %>` syntax for one-off situations.  It should, however, provide a decent catch to prevent XSS attacks in general.

#### Performance Considerations

One final note: the concern about encoding the content as HTML being a performance issue would be considered *premature optimization*.  Chances are **extremely** high that any performance bottlenecks would be somewhere else, and not in the encoding of the content.  Build your application first — using a good design — and optimize later after you can benchmark and analyze the running application.